Why does a list in my class object collect all values added to each instance?
I'm playing around with porting an old BASIC game to Python, and I have written a class Trader which includes a list called manifest and a method to add a pallette of goods to the list.
class Trader():
    """ Create a free trader ship and initialize it. """
    def __init__(self, nomen, regcode, captain, current_port, 
                next_port, cargo_mass, cash_aboard, banknumber, delay_code,
                hold_cap=std_hold_cap, manifest=[], sdate=Datei(1, START_YEAR)):
        """ signature is (str, str, str, int, int, int, int, str, float, /, int, [], ())
        """
        self.nomen = nomen
        # regcode and banknumber are just randomized fluff
        self.regcode = regcode if regcode != -1 else str(uuid.uuid4())[:12]
        self.captain = captain
        self.current_port = current_port
        self.next_port = next_port
        self.cargo_mass =  cargo_mass
        self.cash_aboard = cash_aboard
        self.banknumber = banknumber if banknumber != -1 else str(uuid.uuid4())[4:16]
        self.delay_code = delay_code
        # These next 3 are keyword args:
        self.hold_cap = hold_cap
        self.manifest = manifest
        self.sdate = sdate
        #. end def
    #. end class
    
    def add_lot(self, lot):
        self.manifest.append(lot)
        #. end def
    
    #. end class

So when I initialize the free traders, I add a standard load to the manifest, expecting each ship to get one copy of the list items.  Instead, I find that each ship gets (length of list)*(number of ships) items in its list:
def setup_ships():
    """ The obvious purpose.  
    """
    global traders, players
    print("\nCaptains, name your ships!  ")
    for ix in range(ships_apiece):
        for px in range(num_players):
            if ix == 0:
                # Player class exposes a nomen attribute, and also provides 'leaderboard' data: total_winnings, number_of_wins, etc
                players.append(Player(input(f'Player #{px}, what is your name?  ')))
            # trader gets: nomen, regcode, captain, current_port, next_port, cargo_mass, cash_aboard, banknumber,
            #       delay_code, hold_cap=std_hold_cap, manifest= [], sdate = Datei(1, START_YEAR)
            trader = Trader('', -1, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0)
            trader.captain = answers.pop(0) or input("Who is the captain of player #{0}'s ship #{1}? ".format(players[px].nomen,ix))
            print(f'length of manifest pre-loading: {len(trader.manifest)}')   
            # Give each trader a standard starting manifest
            lot1 = Lot('Misc. Tools     ',LotGroups.MFCD.value,15,15,1.00,1.0)
            lot2 = Lot('Training Corpora',LotGroups.FIRM.value,10, 0,1.00,1.0)
            lot3 = Lot('Medicines       ',LotGroups.MEDS.value,10,10,1.00,1.0)
            trader.add_lot(lot1)
            trader.add_lot(lot2)
            trader.add_lot(lot3)
            trader.cargo_mass = 25
            trader.sdate = Datei(1, START_YEAR)
            trader.cash_aboard = 5000
            trader.nomen = answers.pop(0) or input(f"Captain {trader.captain}, what do you christen your ship?  ")  
            print('trader: ', repr(trader),'\n')
            traders.append(trader)
            
            print(f'length of trader.manifest post-loading: {len(trader.manifest)}')
            del trader  # Get fresh new trader stuff for the next round.
            del lot1
            del lot2
            del lot3
            #. end for px
        #. end for ix
    #. end def

On running this I get multiple copies of the load in each ship.
Captains, name your ships!  
Player #0, what is your name?  Rick
length of manifest pre-loading: 0
trader:  <__main__.Trader object at 0x000001BDCABBE0F0> 

length of trader.manifest post-loading: 3
Player #1, what is your name?  Jeanne
length of manifest pre-loading: 3
trader:  <__main__.Trader object at 0x000001BDCABBE0C0> 

length of trader.manifest post-loading: 6
length of manifest pre-loading: 6
trader:  <__main__.Trader object at 0x000001BDCABBE000> 

length of trader.manifest post-loading: 9
length of manifest pre-loading: 9
trader:  <__main__.Trader object at 0x000001BDCABBE870> 

length of trader.manifest post-loading: 12


 ********************  >>  2185-01-13  <<  ********************
* Beowulf has arrived at Ross 154 Starport.  
Cr on board  +5000.00
Manifest for Beowulf
Lot(nomen='Misc. Tools     ', group=2, tally=15, mass=15, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Training Corpora', group=4, tally=10, mass=0, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Medicines       ', group=3, tally=10, mass=10, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Misc. Tools     ', group=2, tally=15, mass=15, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Training Corpora', group=4, tally=10, mass=0, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Medicines       ', group=3, tally=10, mass=10, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Misc. Tools     ', group=2, tally=15, mass=15, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Training Corpora', group=4, tally=10, mass=0, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Medicines       ', group=3, tally=10, mass=10, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Misc. Tools     ', group=2, tally=15, mass=15, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Training Corpora', group=4, tally=10, mass=0, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
Lot(nomen='Medicines       ', group=3, tally=10, mass=10, value=1.0, pfactor=1.0)
                         Cargo Mass   25t

and ditto for the other three ships in this test game.
Obviously, I am dealing with a class versus instance issue, but how do I fix this?  I thought that deleting the data and starting over with each ship would do the trick: evidently not so.  Help would be appreciated.

manifest=[] is executed ONLY ONCE, when __init__ is defined.  After that, it remembers anything added to it.
